# How to find out what did I block in Opera?

Tags: opera, adblock

I blocked something with Opera's content blocker that I shouldn't have. The blocking rule I set now blocks some important part of a web page (probably a CSS file) and it messes up its entire layout. The problem is that the blocking rule *doesn't show up* when I try to block something on that page. How could I find out what is the rule that messes up that web page?

Comment: did you check preferences->advanced->content->blocked content and/or site preferences?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is caused by the content blocker? Have you tried if the problem stays when you disable content blocking via `opera:config#Network|EnableContentBlocker`?

Comment: Preferences->advanced->content->blocked has a billion rules. Needle in the haystack.

Comment: Yes. Content blocking turned off solves the problem.

Comment: needle gets bigger if you open the web page with the problem, look at the source (ctrl+u) and compare that with the rules.

Comment: Using Opera Dragonfly's network tab and comparing the requested resources with content blocking on and off will be easier. You can copy the list and compare in a text editor or uing diff. I can reproduce blocked stylesheet resources not showing up in content blocking dialog. So this is probably a bug and should be reported to Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Preferences > Advanced > Content > Blocked Content...` will let you edit what content gets blocked globally. If that's too much, and if using the filter on that dialog isn't an option because you don't know the name of the site that you're blocking mistakenly (although typing in the domain name *should* help you to at least unblock anything from the site itself), then the next thing to try would be to right-click on the page, select `Block Content...` from the context menu, and hit the `Details...` button to see what is being blocked specifically on the page you're on (but not globally).

If that still doesn't show you what you're after, fire up Dragonfly (right-click, `Inspect element`), go to `Resources`, and check for any third-party sites in the "Host" column. Worst case scenario, you may need to remove these from sites blocked locally on the page or globally one by one.